# Height of article adjusts with other articles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following javascript fragment:

```
for(var i=1;i<4;i++) 
    { 
        var img= ".img"+i;
        $(img).on("click", function(){
            var art = $(this).closest('article');
            art.css('height', 'auto');
            art.find('p').slideToggle(200);
            if(this.src.indexOf("plus") > -1)
            {
                this.src = "images/min.png";
            }
            else
            {
                art.css('height', '62px');
                this.src = "images/plus.png";
            }
            return false;
        });
        $(img).wrap($('<a>',{href: '#'}));
    }
```

This adjusts the height of my article elements, the problem is that the articles interfere with eachother. I have tried to solve the problem  but with no luck. How can I resolve this problem?

You can see the problem on my website [www.stijnaerts.be](http://www.stijnaerts.be)

For example u click on the + next to 'about me', the height adjusts correctly. Now click on the + next to 'contact', this will adjust the height of the article of contact but also the height of the article 'about me'.

I hope that I explained this problem clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you recreate the error in a JSFiddle so we can see it?

Comment: IMHO, this behaviour is completely acceptable

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/stijn26/XpuHy/7/

How do you mean acceptable? I don't want this behaviour :p

Comment: @stijn26 i don't know it's more about design preferences.. I like symmetry, and in your site the effect is kinda cool :P

Comment: This has entirely to do with CSS styles. Next time, please re-build your issue in a fiddle or some other code editor... JS had nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using display: flex on the container, so it is how flex works by default.
Add "align-items: flex-start;" to your container to get correct heights.

```
.homediv { align-items: flex-start; }
```

Also you shold know that flexbox is not widely supported at this time. Here is a good article http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks for this! Yes I know that flex isn't widely supported, but for now it suffices, maybe later I will edit it to something more widely supported.